# How can i show Google Console all of my pages with SPA

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, sitemap, robots.txt, google-search-console

I have a project on react, created with `create-react-app` and i want to index all of my pages to google search engine, but i am using `react-router` then technically there it is many pages, but google sees just one page. I made some reseach and find out i can create robots.txt and sitemap.txt but how can i create sitemap for all of my pages?

https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ - this site see only first page